# need some help in web scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

i wrote the code which scraps the data from inner link of each code (A code, B code, C code etc...)

if you run my code it scrapes data but not as expected, my expected result is in image below

need to get in cvs file with all column name and data below as in result image i.e **"Group" "category" "code" "long description" "short description"**

[Scraping on this website (HCPCS Codes)](https://www.hcpcsdata.com/Codes)
[[image: Result should be in this format with all fields as column name]

This is the code!

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import csv
    
    baseurl = requests.get("https://www.hcpcsdata.com/Codes").text
    
    baseurlhcpc = 'https://www.hcpcsdata.com'
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(baseurl, 'lxml')
    
    #file = open('hcpccode3.csv', 'w')
    #writer = csv.writer(file)
    
    #writer.writerow(["hcpc code","description"])
    
    
    
    
    
    for table in soup.find_all('tr', class_='clickable-row'):
        hcpc_code = table.td.a.text
        #print(hcpc_code)
    
        description = table.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()
        print(description)
        #writer.writerow([hcpc_code, description])
    
    
    
    codelinks = soup.find_all('tr', class_='clickable-row')
    
    codelinksall = []
    
    
    for items in codelinks:
        for link in items.find_all('a', href=True):
            codelinksall.append(baseurlhcpc + link['href'])
    
    print(codelinksall)
    
    for link in codelinksall:
        r = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    
        for table in soup.find_all('tr', class_='clickable-row'):
            codes = table.td.a.text
            description1 = table.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
            print(codes, description1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you expect to get as a result, here is how I did it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

response = requests.get(url="https://www.hcpcsdata.com/Codes")
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("div",{"class":"body-content"}).find("table",{"class":"table"}).find("tbody")
table_elements = table.find_all("tr",{"class":"clickable-row"})

elements_table = []

for i in table_elements:
  items = i.find_all("td")
  elements = []
  for i in items:
    elements.append(i.get_text().strip())
  elements_table.append(elements)

with open("table.csv","w+") as table:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(table, delimiter=",")
  for i in elements_table:
    csv_writer.writerow([*i])
```

It returns this CSV file:

```
'A' Codes,678,"Transportation Services Including Ambulance, Medical & Surgical Supplies"
'B' Codes,50,Enteral And Parenteral Therapy
'C' Codes,367,Temporary Codes For Use with Outpatient Prospective Payment System
'E' Codes,608,Durable Medical Equipment
'G' Codes,"1,736",Procedures / Professional Services (Temporary Codes)
'H' Codes,88,Alcohol and Drug Abuse Treatment Services / Rehab Services
'J' Codes,824,"Drugs Administered Other Than Oral Method, Chemotherapy Drugs"
'K' Codes,144,Durable Medical Equipment For Medicare Administrative Contractors
'L' Codes,904,"Orthotic And Prosthetic Procedures, Devices"
'M' Codes,117,Medical Services
'P' Codes,56,Pathology And Laboratory Services
'Q' Codes,359,Miscellaneous Services (Temporary Codes)
'R' Codes,3,Diagnostic Radiology Services
'S' Codes,526,Commercial Payers (Temporary Codes)
'T' Codes,109,Established For State Medical Agencies
'U' Codes,4,Coronavirus Diagnostic Panel
'V' Codes,209,"Vision, Hearing And Speech-Language Pathology Services"
```

I hope I could help!